# Cordova requirements state CocoaPods not installed when it is installed

Tags: ios, macos, cordova, cocoapods

I installed CocoaPods both using the recommended method $sudo gem install cocoapods and sudo-less method with --user-install flag, but in either case when I run $sudo cordova requirements I get the same error below:

```
CocoaPods: not installed
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in `help!': [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)
```

I even successfully ran a CocoaPods setup before running the requirements check.  I have also created a .bash_profile with the following entries:

```
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:/Users/stephensmith/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin:$PATH
```

O/S is macOS mojave 10.14.1

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

**Type following command in your terminal**

1. cd ~/.cocoapods/repos
2. git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git

This will solve the problem in most of the cases, please see:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5744